# pipe function arguments to command line arguments in python

Tags: python

I have a python code (`cmd.py`) which accepts files as command line arguments and process using parse_args. I want to pass files from another code (`files.py`) to `cmd.py`, just like passing function arguments.
Can this be done without modifying cmd.py?

Comment: Please clarify: Does `files.py` output a list of files to `stdout` that you want to hand to `cmd.py`, or do you want to call `cmd.py` from within `files.py`, like a function? The answers up to now handle the first case. (And in the second case, your question would be better placed on stackoverflow.com.)

Answer (score 3):

Yes it can be done:

```
cmd.py `files.py`
```

Then first files.py is executed and the output (Example: "file1.txt file2.txt") is the input for the cmd.py.

Example:

```
cat `ls`
```

This "cats" all the files found by ls in the working directory.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things that can be done here. First is simple command substitution:

```
cmd.py $(files.py)
```

One problem here is that if there are any spaces, tabs or newlines in filename then these filenames won't be passed as a single argument and instead split into different arguments where these characters occur.

One alternative is, if `cmd.py` outputs each file on a separate line, you can set the shell `IFS` to only contain a newline:

```
IFS='
'
cmd.py $(files.py)
```

This means that only filenames which contain a newline are a problem, cutting down the number of cases where it will fail.

Another problem is what happens if there are a larger number of files output from `files.py`. It may be that the command line becomes longer than the system can handle (the limiting factor is when the total size of the command line plus some other stuff totals `ARG_MAX` on Linux). The `xargs` program is designed for this situation and if the command line is too long for a single run of a program, it will split it into different runs. If this would help, you can do:

```
files.py | xargs cmd.py
```

Of course this also has potential for problems since it expects filenames that contain problematic characters to be quoted/escaped as you would when entering their names directly in the shell. One option is to change `cmd.py` so that the output is appropriately quoted, however some versions of `xargs` can be made to accept newline separated filenames similarly to setting `IFS` above. If the `-d` option is supported (this is with GNU `xargs` on Linux):

```
files.py | xargs -d '\n' cmd.py
```

Finally, perhaps the best way (now supported by most `xargs` implementations) is if you can have the input files separated by a null rather than a newline. This will easily handle *any* filename without introducing complex quoting since null is the only character not allowed in a Unix filename:

```
files.py | xargs -0 cmd.py
```